# Import path file to mysql db table with python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I do really need your help guys. I am going to save the path of my csv file and insert the path to mysql db table. This is my code. This code just insert the data of the csv not the path file.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import MySQLdb
import glob
UPLOAD_FOLDER ="/var/lib/mysql-files/"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'csv'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
  # this has changed from the original example because the original did not work for me
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print '**found file', file.filename
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

        conn = MySQLdb.connect (host="192.168.1.5", port=3306, user="root",passwd="12345fitri",db="myDb")
        x = conn.cursor()
            print 'filename'
        sql = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{}'
        INTO TABLE test
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        (FILE);"""  

        #"
        os.chdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
        dirfiles=glob.glob("*.csv")
        for file_name in dirfiles:
          print file_name
          if file_name==filename:
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql.format(file_name))
            conn.commit()
            print "hello"
        except Exception:
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            conn.rollback()
            # for browser, add 'redirect' function on top of 'url_for'
            return url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename)
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
#
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000,  threaded=True,debug=True)
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: that is my code. you can check it

Comment: i sent my code already @bernie

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.
I tried it, and it worked.

Please fix `password` and `host` of `MySQLdb.connect`, and `host` of `app.run`.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import MySQLdb
import glob

UPLOAD_FOLDER ="/tmp/"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'csv'])
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
  # this has changed from the original example because the original did not work for me
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print '**found file', file.filename
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

        conn = MySQLdb.connect (host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, user="root",passwd="kani",db="myDb", local_infile = 1)
        x = conn.cursor()
        print 'filename'
        sql = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{}'
        INTO TABLE test
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        """
        os.chdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
        dirfiles=glob.glob("*.csv")
        for file_name in dirfiles:
          print file_name
          if file_name==filename:
            try:
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
                print sql.format(file_path)
                cursor.execute(sql.format(file_path))
                conn.commit()
                print "hello"
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                # Rollback in case there is any error
                conn.rollback()
                # for browser, add 'redirect' function on top of 'url_for'
            return url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename)
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.33.40', port=5000,  threaded=True,debug=True)
```

You should insert `local_infile = 1` to `MySQLdb.connect` in order to use `LOAD DATA` statement.

**EDIT**

Sorry, if you want insert only the path of your csv file, it doesn't need `local_infile=1`.

Simply, please fix your `sql`..

`sql = "INSERT into test (file_path) values ('{}')"`

Is this what you want?

**EDIT**

You can get the file path as follows.

`file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)`

and, by using `format` method,

`sql.format(file_path)`

your sql will be like follows.

`INSERT into test (file_path) values ('/tmp/hoge.csv')`

Could you try above?

P.S

```
    sql = "INSERT into test (file_path) values ('{}')"
    os.chdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
    dirfiles=glob.glob("*.csv")
    for file_name in dirfiles:
      print file_name
      if file_name==filename:
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            print sql.format(file_path)
            cursor.execute(sql.format(file_path))
            conn.commit()
            print "hello"
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            conn.rollback()
```

I hope it goes well.

Comment: is the code can send the directory of the file to mysql db table? because my code just load contain of the csv file.

Comment: but i have to specify the table name for the file path. and how to get the path of the file?

Comment: because i have to get the path file first, and make it as variable, isnt it?

Comment: in my database table give me like this "/var/lib/mysql-files" but i want like this "/var/lib/mysql-files/name of csv file. because i have many csv file. and i want also, if i klik the path file, i will get the file

Answer (score 0):

```
 import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import MySQLdb
import glob
UPLOAD_FOLDER ="/var/lib/mysql-files/"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'csv'])


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
  # this has changed from the original example because the original did not work for me
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print '**found file', file.filename
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        conn = MySQLdb.connect (host="192.168.1.1", port=3306, user="root",passwd="1234",db="myDb")
        x = conn.cursor()
            print 'filename'
        sql = "INSERT INTO mine (filepath) values('/var/lib/mysql-files/', 'filename')"

        os.chdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
        dirfiles=glob.glob("*.csv")
        for file_name in dirfiles:
          print file_name
          if file_name==filename:
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql.format(file_name))
            conn.commit()
            print "hello"
        except Exception:
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            conn.rollback()
            # for browser, add 'redirect' function on top of 'url_for'
            return url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename)
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000,  threaded=True,debug=True)
```

Comment: i tried like that code, but it doesnt work. i dont get the path file in my database table

Answer (score 0):

```
    import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import MySQLdb
import glob
UPLOAD_FOLDER ="/var/lib/mysql-files/"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'csv'])


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
  # this has changed from the original example because the original did not work for me
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print '**found file', file.filename
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        conn = MySQLdb.connect (host="192.168.1.5", port=3306, user="root",passwd="12345fitri",db="myDb")
        x = conn.cursor()
            print 'filename'
        sql = "INSERT INTO mine (what) values('/var/lib/mysql-files/')"

        os.chdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
        dirfiles=glob.glob("*.csv")
        for file_name in dirfiles:
          print file_name
          if file_name==filename:
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            file_path= os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            print sql.format (file_path)
            cursor.execute(sql.format(file_path))
            conn.commit()
            print "hello"
        except Exception:
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            conn.rollback()
            # for browser, add 'redirect' function on top of 'url_for'
            return url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename)
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000,  threaded=True,debug=True)
```